# Got socket error, trying to find package firebase_core_platform_interface

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, pub.dev

I am having a problem when running `dart pub add <package_name>`. Just upgraded to latest flutter version 3.16 and created a new project but couldn't install any packages. I tried previous projects but same error. Tried running terminal as administrator but no luck. can someone verify this is global issue or a way to fix this?

**EDIT**

the error message:

```
Got socket error trying to find package firebase_messaging_platform_interface at https://pub.dev.
exit code 69
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you need to add the following to your system environment variables :

```
name: PUB_HOSTED_URL
value: https://pub.flutter-io.cn

name: FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL
value: https://storage.flutter-io.cn
```